# What do the 'M', 'c' and 'z' mean in SVG paths?

Tags: svg, paperjs, pathelement

http://paperjs.org/examples/

I'm trying to create a custom path with Chain, and I see that Tadpoles has a predefined heart-shaped path, so I'm trying to copy it but I don't understand a few parts of it.

> var heartPath = new Path('M514.69629,624.70313c-7.10205,-27.02441 -17.2373,-52.39453 -30.40576,-76.10059c-13.17383,-23.70703 -38.65137,-60.52246 -76.44434,-110.45801c-27.71631,-36.64355 -44.78174,-59.89355 -51.19189,-69.74414c-10.5376,-16.02979 -18.15527,-30.74951 -22.84717,-44.14893c-4.69727,-13.39893 -7.04297,-26.97021 -7.04297,-40.71289c0,-25.42432 8.47119,-46.72559 25.42383,-63.90381c16.94775,-17.17871 37.90527,-25.76758 62.87354,-25.76758c25.19287,0 47.06885,8.93262 65.62158,26.79834c13.96826,13.28662 25.30615,33.10059 34.01318,59.4375c7.55859,-25.88037 18.20898,-45.57666 31.95215,-59.09424c19.00879,-18.32178 40.99707,-27.48535 65.96484,-27.48535c24.7373,0 45.69531,8.53564 62.87305,25.5957c17.17871,17.06592 25.76855,37.39551 25.76855,60.98389c0,20.61377 -5.04102,42.08691 -15.11719,64.41895c-10.08203,22.33203 -29.54687,51.59521 -58.40723,87.78271c-37.56738,47.41211 -64.93457,86.35352 -82.11328,116.8125c-13.51758,24.0498 -23.82422,49.24902 -30.9209,75.58594z');

I don't understand what the *M* at the start of the path means, or the *c* in some of the values or *z* at the end of the path. I tried to find info about it in their docs or Google it but I can't find what I want because single letters make searching tough.

I tried to remove the *M* at the start and the Tadpoles stopped moving, so I assume M potentially means 'moving'? Removing the *c* alters the shape of the heart, but removing the *z* doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Good reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Comment: Please mark the correct answer as the chosen one, and not the **first** answer you got.

Comment: They mean what the docs say they mean, which can be searched for easily enough with "svg path".

Comment: @vsync If you can explain why an answer that is more or less a copy and paste of part s of a document linked in the chosen answer is better than the chosen one, I'm deleting the latter. SO should be a collaborative environment and by leaving a comment you can help to improve questions and answers.

Comment: @skypjack - the question in the title asks very clearly `What does the 'M', 'c' and 'z' mean in SVG paths?` and your answer does not explains what was asked.. the other answer is much more to the point without leaving any reader with questions.

Comment: @vsync O.o Really? Have you read the question at least? The OP said - _I tried to find info about it in their docs or Google it but I can't find what I want because single letters make searching tough_. Pointing the right document out and explaining why that's the right one is a good approach. SO is not a copy-and-paste service from the official documentation, as far as I remember.

Comment: @skypjack - I give much more priority to what was asked in a title than in the body, and so does google...

Comment: @vsync Got it. I'm not Google and usually I read the questions and try to reply to them, not to their titles. At least I've understood the downvote and I'm proud of it now. Thank you.

Comment: I don't want to offend, but just I think others which would come here from google would probably want to read the other answer as it answers the title, which is much more beneficial to many people who google things than the single person who opened this question (OP)

Comment: Didn't know that marking the answer that led me towards the right direction would spark such an argument. @vsync I don't know why you're getting so worked up about this - when I asked the question I was only looking at Paper.js's documentation, it didn't cross my mind that the Path() they're using is SVG's docs. skypjack cleared that doubt for me, so I marked his answer as the correct one.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The constructor you are invoking is [this](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#path--pathData):

```
Path(, pathData)
```

Where `pathData` is described as:

> the SVG path-data that describes the geometry of this path

The documentation you should read is the one of SVG.
As @GerardoFurtado mentioned in the comments, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) is a read that could be of interest for you.

Comment: Interesting. What's the downvote for? A comment would have helped improving the answer at least.

Answer (score 14):

## M: Move to

The command "Move To" or M, which was described above. It takes two parameters, a coordinate  ' x ' and coordinate ' y ' to move to. If your cursor already was somewhere on the page, no line is drawn to connect the two places. The "Move To" command appears at the beginning of paths to specify where the drawing should start

## z: Close Path

This command draws a straight line from the current position back to the first point of the path. It is often placed at the end of a path node, although not always. There is no difference between the uppercase and lowercase command.

## c: Bezier Curves

The cubic curve, C, is the slightly more complex curve. Cubic Beziers take in two control points for each point. Therefore, to create a cubic Bezier, you need to specify three sets of coordinates.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

-EDIT-

You can visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d for a full reference to all the possible commands and their usage.